# Remember credentials without password

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

I have a login form where people login with their ID and email. They don't have a password. For this reason, the browser wont prompt to save credentials. I have tried changing the ID input to password before form submit, but that is also not working. Here is my current code.

```
<form action="" method="POST" onsubmit="return changeType();">
    <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-cell--12-col">
      <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="email" id="email_id" data-required="" name="eid">
      <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="email_id">Email ID</label>
     </div>
     <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-cell--12-col">
       <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="number" id="Membership_id" data-required="" name="mid">
       <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="Membership_id">Membership ID</label>
     </div>
     <p class="mdl-color-text--red-600"><?php echo $error; ?></p>
     <input class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-button--raised mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect" style="float:right;margin-right: 15px;" type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function changeType(){
    $("#Membership_id").attr("type","password");
  }
</script>
```

Adding a fake password field works, but that won't store the ID value.

Comment: check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp)

Comment: Autocomplete on or off ?

Comment: `autocomplete="off"`

Comment: That removed the auto completion too. Not working @Escoute

Comment: set to password field

Comment: Added a fake password field and added autocomplete="off". Still not working.

Comment: Use the mail or number as password by default. Then when page loads change it back to mail or number if you want them to see it. Then before submitting change back to password. I guess it could work.

Comment: @user5014677 I already tried that. Not working. :(

Comment: Strange. But since adding a fake password field works on submit complete the fake password field with the id. Then when you load the page get the value of that fake field and put it in the id field.

Comment: That should work. But its a complex workaround.